# Swift: How to append string to the same path component of URL

Tags: swift, string, url, types

In Swift, I'm trying to add a string to a URL ***without creating a new path component***.

The only URL methods that I can find are for appending/deleting entire path components, e.g. adding a slash before the addition.

From Apple's documentation of `NSURL.appendPathComponent`:

[image]

Currently, I'm having to convert the URL to a String, add the bit, and then convert back to URL.

The context is: if a folder already exists, keep adding a number until you get a unique name.

```
myIndex += 1
let dirIndex = String(format: "%02d", myIndex)
var tempString = dirURL.path
tempString += dirIndex
dirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempString) as URL
```

Surely there's an easier way?

Comment: assuming you already have a valid `dirURL` var, you could do this: `myIndex += 1` and 
`dirURL.appendPathComponent(String(myIndex))`

Comment: But that gives me `/the/old/filepath/myIndex` instead of `the/old/filepathmyIndex`.

Comment: Maybe you can do this with URLComponents: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easier way.

But you have to use a loop and check if the folder name plus the suffix exists, too. If so you have to remove the suffix and add a new one.

Something like this

```
var myIndex = 0
var dirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myuser/TestFolder")

while FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dirURL.path) {
    myIndex += 1
    var path = dirURL.path
    while path.last?.isNumber == true { path.popLast() }
    path += String(format: "%02d", myIndex)
    dirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
}
```

Or you are working with the path and create the URL at the end

```
var myIndex = 0
var dirPath = "/Users/myuser/TestFolder"

while FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dirPath) {
    myIndex += 1
    while dirPath.last?.isNumber == true { dirPath.popLast() }
    dirPath += String(format: "%02d", myIndex)
}
let dirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)
```

Note: If the base folder name ends with number(s) the number(s) will be cut.

Or another approach which replaces the two trailing digits with Regular Expression. With this version the base folder name can end with number(s)

```
while FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dirPath) {
    myIndex += 1
    if myIndex == 1 {
        dirPath += "01"
    } else {
        dirPath = dirPath.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d{2}$", with: String(format: "%02d", myIndex), options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
let dirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've got a loop, and I used an 'original' basename var outside the loop to add each index onto.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something easier like this:

```
var myIndex = 123
var dirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myuser/TestFolder")

let folder = dirURL.lastPathComponent
dirURL = dirURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(folder + String(myIndex))

print("\n-------> dirURL: \(dirURL) ")
```